# How I keep the number of my terminal windows from rising when I launch Jupyter

Tags: terminal, jupyter

I'm new to Jupyter notebooks and Python. I launched Jupyter notebook from Spotlight, closed it and then launched it again. I did this a few times, each time exiting Jupyter by shutting down my notebook and then closing the browser. Every time I relaunch Jupyter, the number of terminal windows just keeps rising - adding to the previous ones. Even when I quit the terminal (Cmd+Q) and relaunch Jupyter, all the previous terminal windows get activated and start running.

How do I fix this? My screen is literally littered with separate terminal windows.

Regards,
Saunok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter is not a classic application in the sens that it keeps running in the background. Every time you use spotlight to start jupyter you start a new instance of the Jupyter server app.

You can either:

- Shut it down when you quit your notebook by going to the tree view and press quit on the upper right (if you are using classic notebook)
- Or File-> Shutdown if you are using lab.

The other way is to not restart jupyter each time, and just navigate with your browser to `http://localhost:8888` or whatever address jupyter gives you when you start it.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used the first solution you suggested - I'm using Jupyter Notebook. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome Happy for you.